# SHOW TABLE STATS Statement throws error in Hive 1.1.0

Tags: hive

I am executing the query `SHOW TABLE STATS sampletable;` in Hive (1.1.0) and it throws the below error.

```
hive> show table stats sampletable;
MismatchedTokenException(26!=105)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.showStatement(HiveParser.java:21074)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1062)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1055)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1045)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 mismatched input 'stats' expecting EXTENDED near 'table' in show statement
```

I have checked cloudera's document on this particular hive statement and looks like I am executing the right query. Here is the [link](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_show.html#show_table_stats_unique_1) to it.

Not sure what the MismatchedTockenException is. Any help is on this, please?
I am using CDH 5.5.2

Comment: I think this command is for impala, for hive go through this link --  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev

Comment: @KishoreKumarSuthar You are correct. That hive statement was for Impala. Here is the command for Hive. 
`analyze table sampletable partition(year) compute statistics noscan;`